# want to fetch only the month part from a date in mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Is it possible to fetch only the month part from a sql date entry?

like the date is stored like `'2011-01-06'`. if i want to fetch only the `'01'` portion how can I do that?

thanxx in advance.

Comment: Thanks all!! I got my answer!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` to do it, like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateField, '%m') FROM table
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

like :

```
select DATE(date_field) from mytable
```

from manual :

**MONTH(date)**

Returns the month for date, in the range 1 to 12 for January to December, or 0 for dates such as '0000-00-00' or '2008-00-00' that have a zero month part.

```
mysql> SELECT MONTH('2008-02-03');
        -> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

in a mysql query, you can just do this:

```
MONTH(date_field)
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql> SELECT [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)('2008-02-03');

        **Result**: 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`MONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function of MySQL:

```
SELECT MONTH('2011-01-06');
```

**Result:**

```
1
```

To get month name instead, you can use `MONTHNAME` like this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME('2011-01-06');
```

**Result:**

```
January
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try

```
select substring(`mydate_field`,6,2) from `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI-SQL you can use EXTRACT:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT('month' FROM fieldname)
FROM
    tablename;
```

This works in many databases, MySQL as well.